# Android N take photo

Tags: android, file, save, photo, take

I am creating an application that needs to make a photo and store it to the external storage. Now, everytime I click on the button to take a photo it sets the view back to my main activity. What's the matter with my code?

### Report.java:

```
Button button1;
ImageView imageView1;
Uri file;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out, R.anim.slide_in);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        button1.setEnabled(false);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            button1.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}

public void takePicture(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    file = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
}

private static File getOutputMediaFile(){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraDemo");

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "NippesReportIMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            imageView1.setImageURI(file);
        }
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that it doesn't return an error in the android monitor.

### Permissions for camera in manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

### Button XML:

```
<Button
    android:text="Take picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="takePicture"/>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it happening in only Nougat phones?

Comment: @ForamShah well i only tested it on android n devices

Comment: @Bostrot where is your button1 onclick listener?

Comment: @Rishikeshpathak sorry forgot to mention: using android:onClick="takePicture" in the activity xml.

Comment: In your gradle try by giving targetSdkVersion 22,because if you are targetting your app above 22 and device api is also above 22 then you have to give run time permission.

Comment: @Rishikeshpathak thank you! It works with setting the target to 22!

Comment: Please upvote comment so it will help others.Welcome